# Sharepoint 2010 Search Default Content Access Account

Tags: sharepoint, search, sharepoint-2010, admin, account

I have a search set up on my Intranet. I have not allowed certain libraries and lists to be crawled (this helps eliminate the need for so many crawl rules). However...I do need some crawl rules in place, which I added. I ran the Full Crawl and the "excluded" items from the crawl rules still showed up.

I believe this is because my administration account has full control, but I don't know how to fix it.

- I went in to add another account to the service (Manage Service Applications under Central Admin - Administration tab) and the only option it gives me to select is "full control".
- Under the main site accounts (Manage Web Application link on Central Admin) the user I added says full read.

Now then On the main Search Service Page there is an account called "Default Content Access Account". I changed that to be the account that is Full Read from the administration group of the manage web application page. I then cleared the indexing and ran the crawl fresh. The crawl rules are still ignored. Does anyone have any thoughts on this? I am very perplexed.

Comment: For some reason the crawl rules don't want to exclude the /Forms/ folder in each of the libraries. I have tried http://sitename/document library/forms/* and it ignores them. I tried including as the following http://*/Forms/* and it excluded almost all the elements of the search. I also tried the http://localhost:portnumber/document library/forms/* and that excluded all of the items. I am thoroughly confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I never was able to fully solve the issue. I did go into each list and library and under advanced settings selected 'No' for the search being able to crawl it. Though this solution will only go so far.

I still have the issues in my document libraries of the /Form/* content showing up in a search (Which only show up if you search for an item that also appears on the MasterPage).

Anyway, I can live with this half fixed as it is.